# Fortran array combinations

Tags: loops, fortran, fortran90

For instant, lets say I have an array `A =  (/ 2,5,6,11 /)`. I want to get the combinations `(2,5)`, `(5,6)`, `(6,11)`, `(11,2)` for a calculation. Basically, it is `(A(i),A(i+1))`, but must loop with the first element in the array. How do I set up this in FORTRAN?

Appreciate your help. 
Chin

Comment: What have you got so far ?

Comment: I'd append rotated (starting from 2nd element, then first one or [CSHIFT](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CSHIFT.html)) copy and [reshaped](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RESHAPE.html) it to 2D. Perhaps combined with transposition. Or something along these lines.

Comment: Well I am new to programing. I know i, i+1 will get combinations until the array. But how can I cycle last element with 1st element.

Comment: Perhaps something with [MOD](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MOD.html)?

Comment: There is a little problem doing this in Fortran. Since indexing starts from 1, MOD will return zero when A(i+1) = size of the array, which otherwise must be the last index. This perfectly works for other languages starts indexing with 0.

Comment: Of course you could use a mod operation as well in Fortran, aside from letting your array start from 0 or any other integer, you can always shift your indices into the mod space you'd like and shift it back afterwards. Thus, no problem at all using a mod based solution in Fortran...

Answer (score 3):

Given an integer array such as yours

```
A = (/ 2,5,6,11 /)
```

you could declare another array for the combinations

```
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: b
```

allocate it

```
allocate(b(size(a),2))
```

and then populate it

```
b(:,1) = a
b(:,2) = cshift(a,1)
```

you will find that the rows of `b` are the combinations you seek.

I have used, of course, the approach suggested by @mlt in a comment.  As you can see, I have not explicitly used any loops, nor have I bothered with the indices of the elements of any arrays.

I make no claims about the performance of this approach which a compiler is very likely to implement by making a temporary copy of `a` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
program simple
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: A(4) = (/ 2,5,6,11 /)
  integer           :: i, next

  ! Version 1
  do i=1,size(A)
    next = i + 1
    if (next > size(A)) next = 1

    print *, A(i), A(next)
  enddo ! i

  ! Version 2
  do i=1,size(A)
    print *, A(i), A( merge( 1, i+1, ( i==size(A) ) ) )
  enddo ! i

  ! Version 3
  do i=1,size(A)
    print *, A(i), A( mod( i, size(A) ) + 1 )
  enddo ! i
end program
```